# Delete a structure mapped to a file (WinApi)

Tags: file, winapi

I have a structure:

```
struct record
{
    TCHAR teacher[31];
    TCHAR discipline[21];
    TCHAR faculty[21];
    TCHAR group[11];
    TCHAR studentsCount[4];
    TCHAR examDate[31];
    bool isDeleted;
};
...
currentView = (LPBYTE)MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, viewStart, viewSize);
recordView = (record*)(&currentView[viewOffset])
```

How can I delete it from the file?

This doesn't work:

```
delete recordView
```

I've been trying different methods, but with no result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You either need a way to mark records as "empty" so that you know to re-use the space (efficient), or move all subsequent records up to fill the space left by the deleted record (potentially inefficient).

Comment: Now I copy all non-deleted records to deleted ones `memcpy(recordView, recordNotDeletedView, sizeof(record));` and mark notDeleted records as deleted. I wanna get rid of the deleted records and srhink the file size. It seems like a simple task but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: You can use [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to truncate a file.

Comment: File mapping seems like a terrible way to go. What made you choose that? The other thing that I suspect you might not realise is that you can't delete from the middle of a file and expect the content at the end to move down. You'd need to copy it down.

Comment: And just to pick up on your use of delete, you can only ever pass that something that originated with a call to new.

Comment: My teacher made me use file mapping as a way for better understanding how the OS works. "You might not realise is that you can't delete from the middle of a file" - I do realise it. I don't want do delete from the middle of a file. I just want to chop off the last chank of a file. I'll try SetEndOfFile as Jonathan suggested.

Comment: Don't forget to remake your file mapping to the smaller size before you truncate the actual file.